# Meat_search in ActiveAdmin is not working in case user selects datetime as search criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, meta-search

When you access your admin page, search filter used to return the results as expected for dates selected.

    `filter :hash_key
    filter :serial_number
    filter :partner
    filter :created_at`

I have made changes to tables like added few more columns. Now all the search filter works fine except filter:

> created_at

When date is selected, it reflects on the page but the same value is not passed to server.
Usually in working condition query will form like:
*http://.../admin/entitlements?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bcreated_at_gte%5D=2016-02-10&commit=Filter&order=id_desc*

But in current case, query is formed as:
*http://.../admin/entitlements?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bhash_key_contains%5D=&q%5Bserial_number_contains%5D=&q%5Bpartner_id_eq%5D=&commit=Filter&order=id_desc*

It will not have date entry here.

Version i am using:
activeadmin (0.5.1)
meta_search (1.1.3)

If i set the date manually by edit its html source, it starts working but upon reset, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been found with jQuery 1.9 compatibility issue

we need to edit the following file:
*app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/pages/application.js.coffee*
and # Filter form: don't send any inputs that are empty
replace this:

`$(@).find(':input[value=""]').attr 'disabled', 'disabled'`

with

 `$(@).find(':input').filter(-> @value is '').prop 'disabled', true`

You can also change the **gem.lock** file to load this revision by adding the following line:

`remote: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
  revision: 606b88afa99ac6255a07bf68f55336e302327083`

It has worked for me.